# Default value for sql variable when DBNull.Value passed from code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a service that is used between multiple projects. In this service we do the calls to insert/update sql tables using stored procedures. From the project if a variable is empty or null the application should pass through a db null value and in turn sql should set the default value to 'N'. This, however is throwing an exception that a null value cannot be inserted.

Assigning a value to a paramater:

```
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PP_Ref", IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParkingPermit), DBNull.Value, ParkingPermit))
```

This is how the variable is set in the sql stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SaveCustomer]
          @PP_Ref           char(1) = 'N',
```

Exception that is received:

```
     {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Cust_PP_Ind', table 'dbo.Customer'; 
      column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." & vbCrLf & "The statement has been terminated."}
```

The variable passed will populate 'Cust_PP_Ind' (Cust_PP_Ind = @PP_Ref) in the insert and update statement. How do I set the default value through sql and not through code (and allow null value to be passed from code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how default parameter values work unfortunately. The default value applies when the parameter isn't passed, not when the parameter is null. You have two choices (that I can see). The first would be to not pass the parameter if it is empty and keep the stored procedure as it is (I have replaced `AddWithValue` with `Add` because [it is much better practise](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParkingPermit))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PP_Ref", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = ParkingPermit;
}
```

The second would be to set the defaults inside the body of your procedure and leave the calling code as it is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SaveCustomer] @PP_Ref CHAR(1) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET @PP_Ref = ISNULL(NULLIF(@PPRef, ''), 'N');
    --REST OF THE PROCEDURE
END
```